# what's the final output image in multistage build?

Tags: docker

Below is the dockerfile that creates an image:

```
FROM diamol/base AS build-stage                  
RUN echo 'Building...' > /build.txt             

FROM diamol/base AS test-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /build.txt /build.txt
RUN echo 'Testing...' >> /build.txt              

FROM diamol/base
COPY --from=test-stage /build.txt /build.txt
RUN echo 'Done...' >> /build.txt
```

and my understanding is, the final image consists layers of diamol/base and the layer created after the last RUN command as picture below shows:
[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63578999/340790 .

Answer (score 1):

The final image will have all the layers from `diamol/base` as well as two additional layers - one for COPY and one for RUN command.

File `/build.txt` will have the following contents:

```
Building...
Testing...
Done...
```